# Компьютер с двумя сетевыми картами: как объединить две сети?

Tags: windows-10, маршрутизация, xiaomi

Есть такая схема подключений:

```
                           Подсеть 1          Подсеть2
Интернет <---> Модем-роутер <----> Компьютер <----> WiFi роутер <----> Устройство
                                            Большое           Минимальное
                                           расстояние         расстояние
```

Компьютер представляет собой десктоп средней мощности на Window 10 Pro. В дополнение к встроенной сетевой карте в него вставлена вторая сетевая карта. К ней подключен WiFi роутер mi router 4a. Роутер должен находится как можно ближе к устройству, далеко от компьютера.

Такая схема подключения выбрана, чтобы минимизировать задержки сигнала между устройством и компьютером.

Если делать подключение по обычной схеме:

```
                            .-> Компьютер
                           /
Интернет <---> Модем-роутер 
                           \
                            .-> WiFi роутер <----> Устройство
```

То в такой схеме возникают дополнительные задержки на модеме-роутере. Хотелось бы их избежать.

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать так, чтобы вторая подсеть:

1. Имела доступ к интернету и устройство могло взаимодействовать компьютером.
2. Была частью общей сети дома. Чтобы пакеты прозрачно проходили через компьютер. При этом компьютер должен быть оставаться устройством сети доступным для взаимодействия с другими устройствами.

Comment: Вам нужно создать соединение типа «сетевой мост». Если оба роутера подключены по Ethernet, то Панель Управления -> Сетевые подключения. Выделяете оба и в контекстном меню появится нужный пункт.

Comment: Насколько большое расстояние? Если до до 30-50 км, то можно и оптикой с конвертерами, и к ним напрямую просто точку доступа с одного конца, а к ней уже устройство.